# How do I take a screeshot from a video with gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I'd like to take a screenshot of an existing video - either an mp4 or an flv - using GStreamer1.0

I see multifilesink but it looks like that generates a bunch of images. I'd only like 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/media/datos/videos/video.mp4 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! pngenc snapshot=true ! filesink location=frame.png

Comment: how can i give a time offset for the input video to take a screenshot at?